# How can I listen for specific button presses from a parent component in Angular?

Tags: angular

I have a table that is meant to act as a configurable base class. In that class I want to be able to pass a menu with actions for each row:

```
 <table mat-table [dataSource]="tableDataSource" matSort (matSortChange)="sortTable($event)" class="mat-elevation-z8">
        ...
        <!-- action column -->
        <ng-container *ngIf="rowActionIcon?.length" [matColumnDef]="rowActionIcon">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef></th>
            <td mat-cell class="action-column" *matCellDef="let element" [id]="rowActionIcon" (click)="emitRowAction(element)">
                <button mat-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu">
                    <mat-icon>{{rowActionIcon}}</mat-icon>
                </button>
                <mat-menu #menu="matMenu">
                    <button mat-menu-item *ngFor="let action of menuActions"><mat-icon>{{action.icon}}</mat-icon>{{action.label}}</button>
                </mat-menu>
            </td>
        </ng-container>
</mat-table>
```

The action columns shows a button with a dropdown of menu items:

[image]

How can I in my child component that uses this component get these clicks, along with the data for  the row? Ideally I'd like to display that data in a dialog somehow.

The child component defines the menuActions that should exist on the parent table:

```
export class CustomersComponent {
  customers: Customer[];
  selectedCustomer: Customer | null;
  menuActions: MenuItemDefinition[];
  customerColumns: { name: string; dataKey: string; isSortable: boolean }[];
  constructor(private cust_api: CustomerApiService, public dialog: MatDialog) {
    this.customers = [];
    this.selectedCustomer = null;
    this.menuActions = [
      { icon: 'border_color', label: 'Edit' },
      { icon: 'delete', label: 'Delete' },
    ];
    this.customerColumns = [
      {
        name: 'Region',
        dataKey: 'region',
        isSortable: true,
      },
      { name: 'Name', dataKey: 'name', isSortable: true },
      { name: 'Id', dataKey: 'id', isSortable: true },
    ];
  }
```

and in the template:

```
  <app-data-table 
        [isFilterable]="true"
        [isPageable]="true"
        [tableColumns]="customerColumns"
        [tableData]="customers"
        [rowActionIcon]="'more_vert'"
        [menuActions]="this.menuActions"
        >
    </app-data-table>
```

But I'm completely clueless as to how I should dynamically map data and actions to each of the buttons I create in the parent template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Complementary the @Parth M. Dave's answer, to control the actions, you should use the mat-menu-item -not in td (click)-. Just use:

```
<button mat-menu-item *ngFor="let action of menuActions" 
        (click)="doSomething(element,action.label)">
        <mat-icon>{{action.icon}}</mat-icon>{{action.label}}
</button>

doSomething(element:any,action:string)
{
    switch(action)
    {
        case "Edit":
           this.onAction.emit({"action":"EDIT","element":element});
         break;
        case "Delete":
           this.onAction.emit({"action":"EDIT","element":element});
         break;
    }
}
```

But you needn't use a variable "rowActionIcon". In a mat-table the columns are showed if is in the array "displayedColumns", so you should remove the `(click)="emitRowAction(element)"` In the td

the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-o7ao8k?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftable-basic-example.html) it's only the part of "mat-menu"

Comment: I puzzled together what to do based on your addon and the above answer. Thanks both for the input. Now the next step is to open a Dialog with the event data or to delete the row using an api. I assume more events will have to be passed like this

Answer (score 1):

If I am not wrong then you have implemented Parent / child component where parent gives data to child component for display.

So when action perform using child component need to pass output parameter for value as below:

### Parent Component

HTML

```
<app-data-table 
        [isFilterable]="true"
        [isPageable]="true"
        [tableColumns]="customerColumns"
        [tableData]="customers"
        [rowActionIcon]="'more_vert'"
        [menuActions]="this.menuActions"
        (onAction)="onParentAction($event)"
        >
    </app-data-table>
```

ts

```
onParentAction(res:any){
  //@ts-ignore
  if(res.action=="EDIT"){
   your action here ......
  }else if(res.action == "DELETE"){
   your action here ....
  }
}
```

### Child Component

```
  @Output() onAction = new EventEmitter<any>();

  onClickEdit(id: number) {
    this.onAction.emit({"action":"EDIT","id":id});
  }
  onClickDelete(id: number) {
    this.onAction.emit({"action":"DELETE","id":id});
  }
```

Explanation : When user perform any action in child component like
edit then they need to call function called `onClickEdit` with value
of `id`  so using emit method of output parameter value go back to
parent component & parent get object with two pair object `{ action: "EDIT or DELETE" & id value }`

Comment: Using your (onAction) setting made me realize how to move ahead. Thanks for that @parth-m-dave